# resize table height automatically based on image height?

Tags: html, css, drupal-7, drupal-views

i have been pulling my hair out over this and cant figure it out for days, would REALLY appreciate some help :(

I am using Drupal (and Views) to display a page of images. The Images are laid out using a Grid format. (I am willing to change it from Grid to another format if it will help achieve what i need easier).

What I have is 6 images going across and each image has a set width of 150px, the height of the image is set automatically.

The effect i want to achieve is to have the images sit ON TOP of each other, currently the height of the table the images sit on is all the same and there is a gap under each image, i want the images to site exactly under each other with just maybe 1px apart, similar to how they do it on Tumblr.

The code of how the table and images is printed is below, can someone help me? pleaseeee. From my search i THINK that im unable to do this using Tables. is that correct? If so then how would i do it so that i can keep a similar grid effect so images sit 6 next to each other on each row, and then fit nicely on top of each other ?

Thank you so much

```
    <table id="container" class="views-view-grid cols-6">

      <tbody>
              <tr class="block">
                      <td class="col-1 col-first">

      <div class="views-field views-field-field-image-pin">        
<div class="field-content ptpageimg"><div data-edit-id="node/3643/field_image_pin/und/_custom_views">
<div class="field-item"><div class="domeimageo">

    <a href="/members/ptarticle/woolie-003-0">
<img class="pthover" src="/files/styles/150x200/public/images/pinpage/760_w2.jpg?itok=_ux-EGvz" width="150" height="200" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="/ptarticle/woolie-003-0" target="_self">
    <p class="pttext">Woolie 003
    </p>
    </a>
    </div></div></div></div>  </div>          </td>

                      <td class="col-2">

      <div class="views-field views-field-field-image-pin">        
<div class="field-content ptpageimg"><div data-edit-id="node/3642/field_image_pin/und/_custom_views">
<div class="field-item"><div class="domeimageo">
    <a href="/members/ptarticle/085"><img class="pthover" src="/default/files/styles/150x200/public/images/pinpage/tumblr_mohhz9Ce001sor33mo1_1280.jpg?itok=4wFQzr_h" width="150" height="200" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="/ptarticle/085" target="_self">
    <p class="pttext">085
    </p>
    </a>
    </div></div></div></div>  
</div>          
</td>
```

Comment: is this similar to what you want to achieve? [isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html)

Comment: Yes thats it, you see how those are sitting on top of each other even though they have different heights :D 
i tried installing this module but it just seems to mess things up, there is a Views Isotope module, but doesnt work properly for me because i am using the Views Infinite Scroll module on this page so i think they clash

Comment: Aside from a plugin like isotope.js, elements sitting next to each other will go under no matter how high your row is. Unless using lots of floats and/or absolute positioning, this will happen. By default, a `<tr>` is meant to go under its preceding `<tr>` no matter the height. It's a `<table>`'s nature.

Comment: OK, so your suggestion is to use isotope.js and then try to figure out a way to fix the conflict with my other jquery modules running on that page?

Comment: As you can see from the link provided, isotope.js is responsive and rearranges your elements/images to go on top of one another and next to each other. This works well with set width elements (in this case they use 1x1 and 2x2 grid blocks) but you'd have to give it a shot to see if it works. As of right now, you've linked no working demo or example site showing what you've got or what you're trying to do, so it's a little bit of a shot in the dark, but I'm quite sure of this one, given I understand your question properly.

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much, i installed the Views Isotope module for Drupal 7 and it worked a CHARM.. However, i had to disable the Views Infinite Scroll Module on this page because having it enabled broke the Isotope layout :( 
The site we are working on is in Maintenance mode so giving a link here would be useless without user id to login. If there is a way i can give you those information in a PM if you like?

Comment: SO is not meant for PM. I will put my comment as an answer for you to accept/vote; this will be more help for the future than comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in comments:

Aside from a plugin like [isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html), elements sitting next to each other will go under no matter how high your row is. Unless using lots of floats and/or absolute positioning, this will happen. By default, a  is meant to go under its preceding  no matter the height. It's a 's nature.